# how to convert an entire column's datatype from number to timestamp in snowflake

Tags: sql, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, complex-data-types

This statement gives me  an error

```
      SELECT cast(FHEFTJ as Timestamp)
```

however this works for

```
          SELECT cast('108353' as Timestamp)
```

I wanted the entire columns datatype to timestamp so tried the above but it doesn't work

given entry 108353
wanted result as 1970-01-02 06:05:53.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to convert a table of values with FHEFTJ as the column name.  You need to reference the table, though.

```
SELECT FHEFTJ::timestamp
FROM tablename;
```

or

```
SELECT to_timestamp(FHEFTJ)
FROM tablename;
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(FHEFTJ as timestamp)
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: is there a way to alter the table for that particular  column? from number to timestamp

Comment: You'd need to either create a new table (CTAS) with the conversion being done in the select, or you could create a new column and update it to the correct value and then drop the original column.  The CTAS is the easiest and most efficient way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that FHEFTJ is one of the row value you have and its throwing error converting it to timestamp. try_to_numeric function first checks if its a number that can be converted.

SELECT CAST(try_to_NUMERIC(FHEFTJ) as Timestamp)  FHEFTJ_datetimE FROM
(
SELECT '103353' FHEFTJ
union
SELECT '108353' FHEFTJ
union
SELECT 'Somevalue'  FHEFTJ
) ;